# Вызвать функцию в Lua и получить возвращаемое значение в C++

Tags: c++, lua, стек

Как мне получить данные из `Lua` скрипта в С++ коде? Как понимаю обмен данными из скрипта в плюсы идет через особый `LUA-Стек`. Помогите разобраться, положим есть вот такая очень полезная функция на `Lua` :

```
function add( x, y )
    return x + y
end
```

В С++ вот такой код :

```
#include "stdafx.h"
extern "C" {
#include "Lua\lua.h"
#include "Lua\lauxlib.h"
#include "Lua\lualib.h"
}

lua_State* L = NULL;
int from_lua_add(int x, int y) 
{
    int sum;
    lua_getglobal(L, "add");
    lua_pushnumber(L, x);
    lua_pushnumber(L, y);
    lua_call(L, 2, 1);   /* Ошибка */
    sum = (int)lua_tointeger(L, -1);
    lua_pop(L, 1);
    return sum;
}

int main()
{
    L = lua_open();
    luaL_openlibs(L);
    luaL_dofile(L, "script.lua");
    int summ;
    summ = from_lua_add(1, 1);
    printf("the summ from lua is %d\n", summ);
    lua_close(L);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

на вызове `lua_call` происходит краш, ошибка такого содержания :

> unprotected error in call to lua api (attempt to call a nil value)

Что я сделал не так ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Примеры кода можно смотреть тут: http://lua-users.org/wiki/SampleCode
Есть длинный пример работы с Lua из C++ тут: http://lua-users.org/wiki/CallingLuaFromCpp

Приведу короткий пример получения данных из Lua на C. Отличие от С++ небольшое.

http://lua-users.org/wiki/GettingValuesFromLua

Example code for Lua 5.1.1:

returnone.c:

```
#include <lua.h>
#include <lualib.h>
#include <lauxlib.h>

int main()
{
   lua_State *L = luaL_newstate();
   char buff[] = "return 1,'a'";
   int error;
   printf( "%d\n", lua_gettop(L) );
   error = luaL_loadbuffer(L, buff, strlen(buff), "my test") || lua_pcall(L, 0, LUA_MULTRET, 0);
   if (error) {
      fprintf(stderr, "%s", lua_tostring(L, -1));
      lua_pop(L, 1);  /* pop error message from the stack */
   }
   printf( "%d\n", lua_gettop(L) );
   printf( "%s\n", lua_tostring(L,-2) );
   printf( "%s\n", lua_tostring(L,-1) );
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: а с каким скриптом этот код работает ?

Comment: и не очень понятен принцип взаимодействия между Lua и C+.

Comment: Принцип взаимодействия C и Lua описан в руководстве (http://lua.org.ru/manual_ru.html). Ещё подробнее этот механизм описан в книге Роберту Иерузалимски "Программирование на языке Lua".
Если коротко, то всё взаимодействие между С и Lua идёт через стек Lua.
Например, если мы вызываем из С функцию в Lua, то мы должны положить в стек Lua имя функции, и последовательно каждый из её параметров. Потом вызвать функцию lua_call в С, которая запустит функцию в Lua.
Результат выполнения функции в Lua тоже попадает в этот стек. Забирать эти значения можно функциями lua_tolstring, lua_tonumber и т.п.

Comment: как я понимаю, если у меня возникает ошибка `unprotected error in call to lua api (attempt to call a nil value)` это свидетельствует о том, что я не обьявил имя функции или один из ее параметров в стеке?

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Answer (score 3):

> Что я сделал не так ?

Вы полностью проигнорировали обработку ошибок в вашем коде.

Функция `luaL_dofile` возвращает код ответа, который надо анализировать (сюрприз!), а не просто игнорировать. Это же касается и `lua_getglobal` и проч.

Если вы добавите вот такую обработку на компиляцию и запуск скрипта:

```
int err = luaL_dofile(L, "script.lua");
if (err) {
   printf("Cannot dofile: %s", lua_tostring(L, -1));
   lua_pop(L, 1);
   return 1;
}
```

то если файл скрипта вдруг будет не найден, будет выведено сообщение:

```
Cannot dofile: cannot open script.lua: No such file or directory
```

Так же, будут обработаны любые ошибки синтаксиса в самом скрипте, если он вдруг будет написан с ошибками.

Если же эту обработку убрать, то при недоступности файла `script.lua`, будет выведено сообщение как у вас в вопросе.